# What really happened once we write L = L[::-1]?

Tags: python

As we all know L[::-1] reverses L, no matter L is a list or a string

```
>>> l=[1,2,3]
>>> l[::-1]
[3, 2, 1]
>>> s
'abc'
>>> s[::-1]
'cba'
>>>
```

But I wonder what the two colons mean. I know it goes from back to front using '-1' as step length, but can you explain in more depth? Thanks :D

Comment: An answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13005464/42973.

Comment: I am reopening this question because when one does not know what `[::-1]` does, then one does not know that this is all about "slice notation", so it is hard to find the right question.

Comment: @EOL Marking this as a duplicate helps make the link to slice notation.

Answer (score 0):

inside `[]` in python, the language spec parses `:`s into [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) objects.

you can either give it just the one `:`, or two. If you omit values, then they are treated specially (i.e. as end values).

It's described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

More in-depth:

When parsing a program, `[]` are treated differently from other parts of the code;

as seen here:

trailer: '(' [arglist] ')' | '[' subscriptlist ']' | '.' NAME
subscriptlist: subscript (',' subscript)* [',']
subscript: '.' '.' '.' | test | [test] ':' [test] [sliceop]
sliceop: ':' [test]

in the [python grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html)

The bit that's important there is noting that the individual `subscript`s can either be `...` or a single item (in this case `test`), or optional `test`s separated by `:`.

The point is though, that when you do use the `:` in there, it's translated into a slice object, which is just passed to the `__getitem__` object method*.

How your `object` deals with the slice objects it gets passed is up to it's implementation of `__getitem__`. Try doing something like this:

```
class my_class(object):
  def __getitem__(*slices):
    print slices
    pass

c = my_class()
c[1]
c[1:2]
c[1:2:3]
c[:2]
c[::3]
c[1::3]
c[1, 1:, :2, ::3, 1:2, 1::3, object(), [1,2,3,4,5]]
```

Note that all that's happening is that the various objects you put inbetween the `[]` jsut get passed to the `__getitem__` method. The only different between then and any other place in python, is that inside `[]` there is the additional parsing of the `slice()` shortcut syntax `start:end:step`.

*at least it is for any object you create. Soem of the builtins do it a little differently - i think for legacy reasons.